# Defining different types of numbers in C#

Tags: c#, numbers

You can define a number in various ways in C#,

```
1F // a float with the value 1
1L // a long with the value 1
1D // a double with the value 1
```

personally I'm looking for which would a `short`, however to make the question a better reference for people, what are all the other post-fix's to number literals you can apply?

Comment: There is no literal syntax for integral types with smaller range/capacity than `int`, you just create a variable of that type then assign an `int` to it (i.e. `short x = 10;`)

Answer (score 28):

```
Type        Suffix    .NET Framework Type                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
decimal     M or m    System.Decimal
double      D or d    System.Double
float       F or f    System.Single
int         [1]       System.Int32
long        L or l    System.Int64
```

[1] When an integer literal has no suffix, its type is the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong.

When an integer literal specifies only a U or u suffix, its type is the first of these types in which its value can be represnted: uint, ulong.

When an integer literal specifies only a L or l suffix, its type is the first of these types in which its value can be represnted: long, ulong.

When an integer literal specifies both a U or u and L or l suffix, its type is the first of these types in which its value can be represnted: ulong.

Comment: Very good answer. Further answers can be found under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5820721/3604523

Answer (score 3):

## Integer

Suffix - Description

none - first of int, uint, long and ulong

U or u - first of uint, ulong

L or l - first of long, ulong

UL, Ul, uL, ul, LU, Lu, lU, or lu - ulong

## Real

Suffix - Description

none - double

F or f - float

D or d - double

M or m - decimal

Answer (score 2):

for money:

```
decimal mon = 1m;
```

for output:

```
string curr = String.Format("{0:C}", mon);  //output $1.00
```