# C# short/long/int literal format?

Tags: c#, literals, language-specifications

In C/C#/etc. you can tell the compiler that a literal number is not what it appears to be (ie., `float` instead of `double`, `unsigned long` instead of `int`):

```
var d = 1.0;  // double
var f = 1.0f; // float
var u = 1UL;  // unsigned long
```

etc.

Could someone point me to a list of these? I'm specifically looking for a suffix for `short` or `Int16`.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166752/c-compiler-number-literals

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining different types of numbers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262555/defining-different-types-of-numbers-in-c)

Answer (score 450, accepted):

```
var d  = 1.0d;  // double
var d0 = 1.0;   // double
var d1 = 1e+3;  // double
var d2 = 1e-3;  // double
var f  = 1.0f;  // float
var m  = 1.0m;  // decimal
var i  = 1;     // int
var ui = 1U;    // uint
var ul = 1UL;   // ulong
var l  = 1L;    // long
```

I think that's all... there are no literal specifiers for short/ushort/byte/sbyte

Comment: Does this mean you have to cast everywhere you use short/ushort/byte/sbyte? Eg.: somebyte = somebool ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0;

Comment: @mola, yes, unless the desired type is unambiguous (e.g. `byte b = 42;`)

Comment: @mola `somebyte = (byte)(somebool ?  1 : 0);`

Comment: Just to add that upper case and lower case of these literal suffixes are equivalent e.g. `1l` and `1L` both will be treated as long integer but certainly `1L` is more readable than `1l`.

Comment: I think you missed 1e+10 / 1e-10

Comment: these lack https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1058

Comment: @DzmitryLahoda what do you mean? The suffixes discussed in that issue are not implemented yet.

Answer (score 54):

From [Integer literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#integer-literals):

> The type of an integer literal is determined as follows:
>
> - If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by `U` or `u`, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `uint`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by `L` or `l`, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `long`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by `UL`, `Ul`, `uL`, `ul`, `LU`, `Lu`, `lU`, or `lu`, it is of type `ulong`.

And from [Real literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals):

> If no real type suffix is specified, the type of the real literal is double. Otherwise, the real type suffix determines the type of the real literal, as follows:
>
> - A real literal suffixed by `F` or `f` is of type `float`. For example, the literals `1f`, `1.5f`, `1e10f`, and `123.456F` are all of type `float`.
> - A real literal suffixed by `D` or `d` is of type `double`. For example, the literals `1d`, `1.5d`, `1e10d`, and `123.456D` are all of type `double`.
> - A real literal suffixed by `M` or `m` is of type `decimal`. For example, the literals `1m`, `1.5m`, `1e10m`, and `123.456M` are all of type `decimal`. This literal is converted to a decimal value by taking the exact value, and, if necessary, rounding to the nearest representable value using banker's rounding (Section 4.1.7). Any scale apparent in the literal is preserved unless the value is rounded or the value is zero (in which latter case the sign and scale will be 0). Hence, the literal `2.900m` will be parsed to form the decimal with sign `0`, coefficient `2900`, and scale `3`.

Answer (score 10):

If your variable isn't already a short, you have to cast it explicitly :

```
Object s = (Int16) 1;
```

Comment: Side note: I think this causes a boxing conversion.

Comment: It does cause boxing because Int16 is a value type and Object is a reference type.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't one for short. Just use `short s = 1;`.

Comment: Interestingly this compiles: `short z1 = (0 == 1 ? 0 : 1);`

But this does not: `short y = 1; short z2 = (0 == 1 ? 0 : y);` (sorry, no line breaks allowed in comments)

Comment: @yoyo: That's because the `0` in the if branch is converted to an `int` **before** the assignment to `z2`. If you use two `short`s in your branches, the result will again be a `short`. With the if/else, the compiler can't know that your `int` can be represented as `short`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myValue = unchecked((short)0x7F00);
```

The literal is int and thus must be cast to target type.
If a value overflow occurs unchecked is required.

Comment: This is the answer for the original question