# Which int type does var default to?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# short/long/int literal format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820721/c-sharp-short-long-int-literal-format)

[Reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384061.aspx%20) up on the use of `var` in programming, I'm curious about what var defaults to when it's used for an `int` type.  For example, if I use

`var foo = 65535`

will the type be `ushort` or just `int`?  Thanks.

Comment: It's probably Int32, seeing as that's sort of the standard. Why don't you find out? `var num = 65535; Console.Write(num.GetType().Name)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Really, what you're asking is **What type is given to integer literals in C#?**, to which the answer can be found in the specification:

(Section 2.4.4.2 of the 4.0 spec)

> The type of an integer literal is determined as follows:
>
> - If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by U or u, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: uint, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by L or l, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: long, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by UL, Ul, uL, ul, LU, Lu, lU, or lu, it is of type ulong.
>
> If the value represented by an integer literal is outside the range of
>   the ulong type, a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: Thank you.  You're answer was very descriptive, and helpful.

Answer (score 6):

All integer literals are of type `int`, so your variable will be `int` unless you cast or add an explicit type qualifier at the end:

```
var quick = 65535;         // int
var brown = (ushort)65535; // ushort
var fox = 65535L;          // long
```

Comment: `unsigned` doesn't work in C#. I think you meant to use `ushort`.