# Implicitly typed variables initialization at compile time

Tags: c#, compilation, var

when i was reading about implicitly typed variables, this question came in my mind. 
i couldn't find the answer on internet so decided to put it hare.

suppose i declare a variable using 'var' keyword.

```
var i = 10;
```

after compilation, i is compiled/treated  as 'Integer' i.

now, my question is  why 'i' is not compiled to 'short' as value of 'i' very much small to be fit into 'Short' data type; and why it is always compiled to 'Integer'  ??

Comment: Format for c# constants:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820721/c-sharp-short-long-int-literal-format

Comment: Yep, 10 is int constant, not short.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the [C# Specification 2.4.4.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) dictates that if a number literal has no decimal or suffix, it's a the smallest of `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong` that can contain it. Naturally `10` fits `Int32` so it is chosen.

> The type of an integer literal is determined as follows:
>
> - If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong.

The C# language designers decided that even though `10` can be fit in an `Int16`, usage of that variable type would be relatively rare; that `Int32` usage would be the "status-quo".

Actually, if memory serves, there is *no* `Int16` literal in C# anyway. You'd have to explicitly declare and assign a value to an `Int16` to get one.

---

<sub>Interestingly, I looked at the compiled IL code and declaring a `short s = 10` and `int i = 10` actually generate the exact same IL... so now I'm wondering how shorts are managed; perhaps they are actually managed as 32 bit values in the CLI anyway. I'd love to find out if this is the case.</sub>