# cast short to int in if block

Tags: c#, casting

I have the following code:

```
Int16 myShortInt;  
myShortInt = Condition ? 1 :2;
```

This code results in a compiler error:

> cannot implicity convert type 'int' to 'short'

If I write the condition in the expanded format there is no compiler error:

```
if(Condition)  
{  
   myShortInt = 1;  
}  
else  
{  
   myShortInt   = 2;  
}
```

Why do I get a compiler error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code is being compiled, It looks something like this:

for:

```
Int16 myShortInt;  
 myShortInt = Condition ? 1 :2;
```

It looks somthing like

```
Int16 myShortInt; 
var value =  Condition ? 1 :2; //notice that this is interperted as an integer.
myShortInt = value ;
```

while for:

```
if(Condition)  
{  
 myShortInt = 1;  
}  
else  
{  
 myShortInt   = 2;  
}
```

There is no stage in between to interperate the value as int, and the literal is being treated as a Int16.

Comment: I'm guessing the ternary operator is generic; something like `public T operator ?:<T> (bool condition, T a, T b)` and the compiler believes that `T` in this instance is an `int`, because both inputs are `int`s.

Answer (score 7):

You get the error because literal integer numbers are treated as `int` by default and `int` does not implicitly cast to `short` because of loss of precision - hence the compiler error. Numbers featuring a decimal place, such as `1.0` are treated as `double` by default.

This answer details what modifiers are available for expressing different literals, but unfortunately you cannot do this for `short`:

[C# short/long/int literal format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820721/format-for-short-long-and-int-literal-in-c)

So you will need to explicitly cast your `int`:

```
myShortInt = Condition ? (short)1 :(short)2;
```

Or:

```
myShortInt = (short)(Condition ? 1 :2);
```

---

There are cases when the compiler can do this for you, such as assigning a literal integer value that fits inside a `short` to a `short`:

```
myShortInt = 1;
```

Not sure why that wasn't extended to ternary actions, hopefully someone can explain the reasoning behind that.

Comment: `unfortunately you cannot do this for short` Damnit... I was so sure there was something like `1s` for short... Oh well, +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Plane numbers like `1` and `2` are treated as integers by default, so your `?:` returns an `int`, which has to be converted into `short`:

```
Int16 myShortInt;  
myShortInt = (short)(Condition ? 1 :2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
Int16 myShortInt;  
myShortInt = Condition ? (short)1 : (short)2;
```

or

```
myShortInt = (short) (Considiton ? 1 : 2);
```

but yeah, as Adam already answered C# considers whole number literals as ints except in the super simple cases like the one you stated:

```
short x = 100;
```