# wrong result from multiplication operation

Tags: c#

I am trying to multiply two numbers in my application but in some case it result wrong value

```
var result = 0;
var firstNumber = 654165;
var secondNumber = 6541;
result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
```

it result `-16074031` which is wrong

can you help me to found where is the error?

Comment: The problem is your variable type `int`. You need to change it `int64` or `long` which is the same

Comment: This is considering as `integer` this case, you need `long` instead `var`. Please look [Format for 'short', 'long', and 'int' literal in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820721/format-for-short-long-and-int-literal-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
checked
{
    var result = 0;
    var firstNumber = 654165;
    var secondNumber = 6541;
    result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
}
```

this way you can see the problem `System.OverflowException`. To solve simply use `long`

```
unchecked
{
    var result = 0L;
    var firstNumber = 654165L;
    var secondNumber = 6541L;
    result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
}
```

Take a look at [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) and [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) keywords.

Comment: +1 for the long-literal postfix. I didn't know that one offhand!

Answer (score 4):

Your implicitly-typed variables are all being created as `int`, but the result of your calculation will only fit in a `long`, so you are seeing an overflow error.

If you simply declare `result` as a `long` instead, you will still see the wrong result, because the operation is performed on two `int`s and not converted to `long` until the assignment, by 
which time the overflow has already occurred.

So instead, you need to either declare one (or both) of your numbers as `long`, or cast one (or both!) to `long` during the calculation. You can also omit the redundant assigning of `0` to `result:

```
int firstNumber = 654165;
int secondNumber = 6541;
long result = (long)firstNumber * secondNumber;
```

or:

```
long firstNumber = 654165;
int secondNumber = 6541;
long result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
```

Comment: `+1` for the best answer so far because this answer also explains a lot the cause of the problem..

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an overflow.

Use `long` instead of `var` for the three declarations and it will gives you the right result.

```
long result = 0;
long firstNumber = 654165;
long secondNumber = 6541;
result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
```

Using `var` the compiler assign the type `Int32` to your variables.

The result is `4,278,893,265` which is greater than [Int32.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) (which is  `2,147,483,647`)

Answer (score 1):

You have a overflow. You should be using a type larger than 32bit. (long for example, double for decimals)

Comment: Writing as a solution would be nice for OP.

Answer (score 0):

use long in spite of using var for all declarations , then you will get correct output

Comment: He doesn't need to declare as a `long` all variables here.

Answer (score 0):

The result should be of type `long`

You can do this by changing to.

```
var result = 0L;
var firstNumber = 654165L;
var secondNumber = 6541L;
result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
```

The multiplication is creating a number bigger than an int and is overflowing.