# Replacing byte in file

Tags: c#, hex, binarywriter

I'm trying to replace certain bytes from a file with some other specific bytes, but have a problem with my binary writer replacing too many bytes. What is wrong in my code?

```
using (BinaryWriter bw = 
    new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, 
        FileMode.Open)))
{
    bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x3;
    bw.Write(0x50);
}
```

This was supposed to change the letter "E" (hex 0x45) with the letter "P", but instead changes that byte and 3 more bytes; from "45 30 31 FF" to "50 00 00 00". I would like to keep the "30 31 FF", only change "45" to "50".

Comment: You might want to check this post about short notations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820721/c-sharp-short-long-int-literal-format#5820772

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you don't want or need to use `BinaryWriter` for this. You're calling [`BinaryWriter.Write(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24e33k1w(v=vs.110).aspx) which is behaving exactly as documented.

Just use `FileStream` to write a single byte:

```
using (var stream = File.Open(fileName))
{
    stream.Position = 3;
    stream.WriteByte(0x50);
}
```

Simpler, easier to read (it's obviously only writing a single byte), and does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because method `Write` actually write `int` (4 bytes). You should convert your value to `byte` type. `bw.Write((byte)0x50);`