# UInt weird compile time behaviour - returning a Long..?

Tags: c#, .net

The following code prints `UInt32`:

```
var myUint = 1U;
Console.WriteLine(myUint.GetType().Name);
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5820772) SO answer I wanted to see what would happen if you try to use the `U` literal suffix with a compile-time negative number. This code (changing`1U` to `-1U`) prints `Int64` (`long`):

```
var myUint = -1U;
Console.WriteLine(myUint.GetType().Name);
```

I thought it would just be a compile time error, but instead returns a `long` with the value `-1` - what is going on? Why does the compiler do this??

Comment: Unsigned values cannot be negative.  The C# compiler punts for the next larger signed integral type to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 3):

The minus sign is not a part of the integer literal specification. So when you write `var x = -1U`, the following rules are applied by the compiler:

> If the literal is suffixed by U or u, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `uint`, `ulong`.

So that's the `1U` part becoming a `uint` / `UInt32`, so far conforming to your expectations.

But then the minus is applied:

> For an operation of the form `-x`, unary operator overload resolution (§7.3.3) is applied to select a specific operator implementation. The operand is converted to the parameter type of the selected operator, and the type of the result
>   is the return type of the operator. The predefined negation operators are:
>
> - Integer negation:
>
>   `int operator -(int x);`
>
>   `long operator -(long x);`
>
> [...]
>
> **If the operand of the negation operator is of type uint, it is converted to type long, and the type of the result is long.**

So the type of the expression `-1U` is `long`, as per the C# specification. This then becomes the type of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously -1U cannot be stored as a uint. Since you use var, the compiler deduces the type to hold the value. Since you want to hold -(1 as unsigned integer), the compiler decides to store it as long.

You would get a compile time error if you defined your type explicitly:

`uint myUint = -1U;`

Comment: It's the compiler that *deduces* the correct type. Not the framework per se.

Comment: _"Since you use var, the framework decides on the datastructure to use to hold the value"_ - that doesn't have to do with `var`. The expression after the assignment operator isn't influenced by the `var` declaration.

Comment: CodeCaster, var is used to define the type implicitly. The compiler decides on the type based on the value.

Comment: The type of the _variable_ (`myUint`), not the type of the literal.

Comment: Yes, and that is why the type of the variable becomes long.

Comment: I prefer deduce over decide just because it's really not got a lot of *choice* here. The expression to the right of the assignment must have a type that the compiler knows, irrespective of the fact that in this circumstance, it's also being used to type a variable.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It does sound better. Though, I am not a native, so I am not coming quickly with these words. Feel free to edit and correct the wording/grammar :-)

Comment: Actually, in some very very specific cases, the compilation of the expression to the right of the assignment operator will in fact be influenced by `var`. Try `FormattableString x = $"{DateTime.Now}";`, inspect the compiled code, then change `FormattableString` to `var` and inspect the compiled code. Not very useful or interesting though, and completely besides the point related to the topic here.