# Feet to Meter Converter in C# is broken?

Tags: c#, decimal, division

I'm trying to make a simple feet to meter converter, but this happens:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CoolConversion
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        decimal feet;
        decimal meter;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            feet = Convert.ToDecimal(Feet.Text);
            meter = feet / 3.281;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I have currently. At first, `feet` & `meter` were int, but I couldn't divide an int by 3.281. I changed them to decimals and now I have this error:

> Error CS0019  Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'decimal' and 'double'

If I can't divide decimals by ints, and if I can't use the `/` symbol on decimals, how am I supposed to divide by decimals?

Comment: Convert `3.281` to a decimal as well? You can use a literal suffix to write it as `3.281m`.

Comment: You need to tell C# that your constant is a decimal by adding an 'm' like this `meter = feet / 3.281m;`. Alternatively you can make your variables doubles.

Comment: Try `meter = feet / 3.281m` using just `3.281` tells the compiler to use a `double` while `3.281f` tells it to use a `float`. Likewise, `3.281m` tells it to use `decimal`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# short/long/int literal format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820721/c-sharp-short-long-int-literal-format)

Comment: @bradbury9 I wouldn't say it's quite a duplicate of that particular post since the OP there knew what suffix specification was. I definitely believe that is a useful post for future readers though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that the compiler is thinking that your constant `3.281` is of type `double`. If you intend to use a type such as `decimal` you'll have to append the `m` suffix. Likewise with `float` types you have to append the `f` suffix. Per MSDN:

> By default, a real numeric literal on the right side of the assignment operator is treated as `double`.

---

### [`float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float)

> Therefore, to initialize a `float` variable, use the suffix `f` or `F`, as in the following example:
>   `float x = 3.5F;`

---

### [`double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double)

> However, if you want an integer number to be treated as `double`, use the suffix `d` or `D`, for example:
>   `double x = 3D;`

---

### [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)

> If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as `decimal`, use the suffix `m` or `M`, for example:
>   `decimal myMoney = 300.5m;`

---

### My Advice

You should really determine which type you'll actually be needing to use prior to using it. In the case of converting *feet* to *meters* I would use either `double` or `float`; `double` is typically the case because it is more precise.

```
private double feet = 0.0d;
private double meters = 0.0d;

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    feet = Convert.ToDouble(Feet.Text);
    meters = feet / 3.281d;
}
```

The `decimal` type is typically used to hold monetary values, where `double` and `float` are used for calculations such as this. Also, it's not a requirement, but if you're ever working with multiple similar types such as the case of `float`, `double`, `decimal`; it's always a good idea to use the suffix for each to clearly relay which type you're intending to use.

---

### Final Note

You can cast to `decimal` as others have pointed out, but it's an unnecessary cast when you can just specify `decimal` by using `3.281m`. In an environment where performance matters, you should avoid unnecessary casting whenever possible.

On another note, you should really ensure that the text you're attempting to convert is a valid value prior to attempting to convert it. I prefer to use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) (all numeric types should have a `TryParse` method if I remember correctly). The reasoning behind this is that if I type `123a` into your text box with the way your method currently works, it'll blow up right then and there. Fixing this is really straight forward:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (double.TryParse(Feet.Text, out feet))
        meters = feet / 3.281d;
    else
        MessageBox.Show($"You've entered an invalid value: {Feet.Text}.");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, `3.281` by itself is a double floating point precision number. You can use the `decimal`-literal notation by adding a `m` to the end of the number.

```
meter = feet / 3.281m;
```

For brevity sake, if you're ever using a variable that is declared as a `double` you can always just cast it to a decimal in the event you need to perform a calculation with two different types in each operand.

```
double feetToMeterValue = 3.281;
meter = feet / (decimal)feetToMeterValue;
```

This works for other types as well, but just be aware you will lose precision when casting to specific types i.e. `double` > `float` and the more obvious `decimal` to `int`.

Comment: casting vs exclicit declaring the correct type. I would definitely go the second choice.

Comment: @bradbury9 Updated to add a bit more brevity to the answer, because explicit initialization is the better answer; you're right. But casting will always have it's uses as well so it's worth noting.