# Why c# treats 0 as int and not as short/decimal etc?

Tags: c#

In c# when i say :

```
var s = 0;
```

what should be type of `s` ? it makes it `int32`. then seems like `var` is not usable for types like `short` and others(?).

Comment: Adrian, that's a point that's quite well-explained in the spec, though.

Comment: Seems there is no literal for short :(

Answer (score 7):

Look at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262555/defining-different-types-of-numbers-in-c-sharp) at StackOverflow.

You can specify a postfix for all numbers.

```
var i = 0;
var d = 0d;
var f = 0f;
var l = 0L;
var m = 0m;
```

Comment: To be specific, those postfixes are for double, float, long, and [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) respectively. There are also postfixes for unsigned ints and longs (`U` and `UL`).

Answer (score 5):

As per the C# language standard, specifically [§2.4.4.2 on integer literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674.aspx):

> The type of an integer literal is determined as follows:
>
> - If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by `U` or `u`, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `uint`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by `L` or `l`, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `long`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by `UL`, `Ul`, `uL`, `ul`, `LU`, `Lu`, `lU`, or `lu`, it is of type `ulong`.

The first rule is all that needs to be applied here. The literal `0` has no suffix and can be represented as type `int` (or, in BCL terms, `Int32`), so that's the type it has.

As you can infer from the above, to change the type of a literal, you can append a suffix to it. For example, the literal `0u` will be of type `uint`. Alternatively, you could explicitly cast the literal to a different type; for example: `(short)0` would cause the compiler to treat the literal as a `short`.

Answer (score 4):

From the specification (§ 2.4.4.2):

> If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`.

So smaller types are not automatically inferred. You can add a cast to force such a smaller type:

```
var s = (short)0;
```

Comment: then its good to write short s =0;  atleast it is shorter version.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you probably knew that before. I got the impression that your confusion stems from why the compiler won't treat `0` as short automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler infers the type to be `Int32`. And you cannot implicitly cast it to a `short` or `byte` because they are smaller in size and you could lose data.

If you'd like the compiler to infer `decimal` you can:

```
var s = 0M;
```