# Simple math gone wrong

Tags: c#, math

I'm missing something obvious i guess. Or have some stupid mistake in my head, but anyway I can't figure it out.

My code is this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ringNumber; i++)
{
    float x = (radius * ringNumber) - (i * radius);
    float y = (-1/2 * radius * ringNumber) - (i * 1/2 * radius);
    Debug.Log ("Radius: " + radius + ", Ringnumber : " + ringNumber + ", i : " + i);
    Debug.Log ("In Loop 3 Vertical : " + x + "  " + y);
}
```

what I get is

[image]

For `Radius = 2` and `Ringnumber = 2`, `Y` is given out as `0` both times. In my mind it should be -2 and -3. Why isn't it?

I have similar mistakes in other loos like this, but some work out just fine.
Its not that difficult math I thought -2*2/2 minus zero times something. Should be -2 or not?

Comment: Standard bug, 1/2 always produces 0.  You need 1/2f to get a floating point division.

Comment: Or use `radius/2` or use `0.5*radius`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does integer division in C# return an integer and not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the point:

> 1.0/2.0 = 0.5 and 1/2 = 0

When dividing integer values the result would be an integer too. So `1/2` would round to zero.
Use `1.0/2.0`

```
for (int i = 0; i < ringNumber; i++)
{
        float x = (radius * ringNumber) - (i * radius);
        float y = (-1.0/2.0 * radius * ringNumber) - (i * 1.0/2.0 * radius);
        Debug.Log ("Radius: " + radius + ", Ringnumber : " + ringNumber + ", i : " + i);
        Debug.Log ("In Loop 3 Vertical : " + x + "  " + y);
}
```

As a best practice always use numeric values with like this: `#.0` this prevent such errors. Also you can try this alternative. [more suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262555/defining-different-types-of-numbers-in-c-sharp)

`1d/2d`  = 0.5

This way you explicitly say that those values are double and are not integers. So the resulting value will also be double too.

Comment: you should also explain why

Comment: Yeah just as I posted it I saw that everywere I used 1/2 is went wrong. 0.5f  workes as well. Do you know why that is?